# rspec - Failure/Error: @users.should eq([user]) - got: [] instead

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

Spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns @users" do
      user = User.create(:email => 'bob@test.com', :password=>'12', :password_confirmation=> '12')
      get :index
      assigns(:users).should eq([user])
    end

    it "renders the index template" do
      get :index
      response.should render_template("index")
    end
  end

end
```

Code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users=User.all
  end
end
```

Error:

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET index assigns @users
     Failure/Error: @users.should eq([user])

       expected: [#<User id: nil, email: "bob@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$JRFUhZxmw1jVCVRFx1bkIO9dpiJbVpbBhlXkGq.zbVyj...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, admin: nil>]
            got: []

       (compared using ==)
```

Comment: I would suggest installing the pry gem under development and test, insert `binding.pry` right after the `User.create` line in users_controller_spec.rb, and do a `user.valid?` and `user.errors` inside the pry console.

Comment: Always use `create!`/`save!` when setting up tests. This ensures that unintended validation issues blow up obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the password of '12' was too short.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid that problem in the future is using factories and including factory specs so you can rest assured you're using valid objects.

Thoughtbot describes a nice approach to this using their very own FactoryGirl in [this blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/30994874643/testing-your-factories-first). I'm not a big fan of the rake task, but the factory spec they recommend is pretty useful.